# how to write join in web api and retrive fields from both tables

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Here i want to join another table and retrive some fields from both tables. 
I tried these

```
 public async Task<List<CreateProjectStructureEntity>> GetProjectStructure1ReportData(string ProjectCode)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (dataBaseContext != null)
                       return await dataBaseContext.CreateProjectStructure.Where(s => s.ProjectUnitCode == ProjectCode).ToListAsync();

                    return null;


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

Any help will be Appriciated!

Thanks

Comment: And your problem is? What's not working?

Comment: @Chris Pratt Actually i don't know how to use join

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this issue.

```
public async Task<List<CreateProjectStructureEntity>> GetProjectStructure1ReportData(string ProjectCode)
{
    try
    {
        if (dataBaseContext != null)
            //return await dataBaseContext.CreateProjectStructure.Where(s => s.ProjectUnitCode == ProjectCode).ToListAsync();
            return await dataBaseContext.Create_Project_Structure.FromSql(@"select cast(Project_Structure_Element_Mapping.Quantity as int) as Auto_ID,Project_Structure_Element_Mapping.Element_Code as Structure_Code,Structure_Description,BuildingTypeMaster.Building_Type_Name as Building_Type_Code,FloorMaster.FloorName as Start_Floor,End_Floor,Create_Project_Structure.Created_By,Create_Project_Structure.Created_Date,Create_Project_Structure.Updated_By,Create_Project_Structure.Updated_Date,Create_Project_Structure.IsDelete, UnitMaster.Project_Unit_Name as Project_Unit_Code,SiteMaster.Site_Description as Site_Code from Create_Project_Structure
     inner join SiteMaster on SiteMaster.Site_Code=Create_Project_Structure.Site_Code
      inner join BuildingTypeMaster on BuildingTypeMaster.Building_Type_Code=Create_Project_Structure.Building_Type_Code
      inner join FloorMaster on FloorMaster.FloorCode=Create_Project_Structure.Start_Floor
      inner join UnitMaster on UnitMaster.Project_Unit_Code=Create_Project_Structure.Project_Unit_Code
      inner join Project_Structure_Element_Mapping on Project_Structure_Element_Mapping.Structure_Code=Create_Project_Structure.Project_Unit_Code



        where Create_Project_Structure.Project_Unit_Code='1002'" ).ToListAsync();
        return null;


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```